# Azure AD and Microsoft Account login in one app

Tags: adal, azure-active-directory

We are building a new SaaS product (web app, API services & mobile clients eventually) that needs to authenticate users via Azure AD or a Microsoft Account. We plan to add support for Google/Github logins in the future.

Our web app is a single-page-app and we are planning to use OpenIdConnect protocol to authenticate against different IdPs.

We looked at using AAD v2 endpoint that supports AAD + MSA login, but the current [limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-v2-limitations) are a deal breaker for us (specifically, the need to use only one appId for all apps & services and lack of on-behalf-of flow). So we decided to integrate AAD and MSA in our app separately.

Given all the changes happening with Azure AD v1 & v2 endpoints and AAD B2C Service, is this the best way to go about this? We want our users to login with their (AAD based) work accounts or personal Microsoft accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding, the Azure AD B2C is recommend if you want the app to support the both social account and work/school accounts in Azure AD.

The B2C tenant already supports **Microsoft Accounts**, Facebook, **Google+**, LinkedIn, and Amazon. And Microsoft will add support for other popular social identity providers based on customer demand.

You can submit the feedback from [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback) if you want the B2C tenant to support GitHub.

Comment: Your proposed solution to use Azure AD B2C doesn't support work/school accounts today and AFAIK, there are no plans for it. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: There is another accounts named **local accounts** in Azure AD B2C tenants. We can also created the local accounts on Azure AD portal as the normal Azure Active Directory. And it is still able to login-in the Azure AD B2C tenant using the username like xxx@xxx.onmicrosoft.com. Does it work for your scenario?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Our SaaS app needs to let users from other AD tenants to signup/login. Essentially, we need multi-tenant Azure AD support for work accounts. Hence, Azure B2C doesn't work for us, it will only give us social identity providers.

Comment: Did the ** lack of on-behalf-of flow** mean **Web API on-behalf-of flow**?  And you only want to register one app for work/school accounts and Microsoft Account?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by **Web API on-behalf-of flow** but this doc article about AAD v2 limitations lists what I mean by **lack of on-behalf-of flow**. My only requirement is to be able to let users with MSA or Work accounts login to our app. For example, a user with joe.developer@outlook.com should be able to signup and login. Also, another user with jane.developer@somecompany.com work account can sign up and login. Hope this makes things clear. How would I go about this?

Comment: We can integrate the web app with Azure AD v2.0 endpoint to enable both work/school and Microsoft account to login-in the web app. And if your apps also require users to signup before then login, we need to implement the business logic ourselves.  The **Web API on-behalf-of flow** is the section from document about AAD v2 limitation. Please feel free to let me know if I misunderstood.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. AAD v2 would meet our requirements, but its limitations are a dealbreaker for us. So how do I achieve what AAD v2 can do myself?